# How to use the credentials expired property in Symfony AdvancedUserInterface?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

In a Symfony 2.4 project our client wants to force the users to change their password every N days. We saw that there are columns "credentials_expired" and "credentials_expire_at" in the database and a check that throws an AccountExpiredException in the UserChecker class that seem to be for that purpose, but I can't find any documentation on how to enable or configure this feature.

- How can the credentials_expire_at column be filled with a date N days after now on every password change?
- How can a user still change the password, if the password is expired?
- How to warn the user about the passoword expiration some days in advance?
- Is it possible to forbid the reuse of the last password?

Comment: This question is definitely too broad as it contains 4 sub-questions. Could you split those up into single questions please?

Comment: You can take a lot of inspiration from [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md). They solved a couple of these issues.

Comment: repeated the question in the symfony issue tracker: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12177

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's the `CredentialsExpiredException` you want to catch. If you're using the [Symfony Security component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form), then the simplest way to handle this is to check for the exception in the `loginAction` of your `SecurityController`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CredentialsExpiredException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

...

$error = $this->get('session')->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);

// check if credentials have expired
if ($error instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
    // display the change password form
    return new Response($this->renderView('AcmeDemoBundle:Security:changePassword.html.twig'));
}
```

You'll obviously need to create a route for changing passwords, which you can set as the form action of your `changePassword` template. Password change requests can then be handled accordingly in your `SecurityController`.

The core of your business logic can/should exist within a `UserManager` (or whatever you wish to call it) service class, which you can instantiate and invoke as needed from your `SecurityController`.

Hope that helps.

NOTE: For posterity, the expired user object is stored within the `CredentialsExpiredException` exception, so you can easily retrieve it if you need to act upon it for handling expired passwords:

`$error->getUser();`